# Compiler error saying I do not override abstract method keyReleased

Tags: java, jframe, geometry, keylistener, mouselistener

Writing a program that should draw shapes when given instructions. 
Here are the instructions. However whenever I compile I get the message

> DrawShapes is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent) in java.awt.event.KeyListener".

I've already put the method `keyReleased` in the program so I don't know why it keep saying I haven't override the abstract method `keyReleased`. I haven't been able to compile the program, but I'm also fairly certain the program wouldn't work even if it compiled. Thank you!

> Write a program that will allow the user to draw a shape with a mouse.
>   The shape to draw should be determined by keyPressed event using the
>   following keys: c draws a circle, o draws an oval, r draws a rectangle
>   and l draws a line.  The size and placement of the shape should be
>   determined by mousePressed and mouseReleased events.  Display the name
>   of the current shape in a JLabel in the SOUTH region of a
>   BorderLayout.  The initial shape should default to a circle.  Make
>   sure the shape displays in the direction of the movement of the mouse.
>   Use JFrame and Paint .  You should have two files: ShapesViewer and
>   DrawShapes (20 points)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DrawShapes extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
String key;


  public DrawShapes()
  {
    this.setSize(300, 300);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.add(new PaintSurface(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setVisible(true);
  }

  private class PaintSurface extends JComponent
  {
    ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

    Point startDrag, endDrag;

    public PaintSurface() {


      this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
      {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
          startDrag = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
          endDrag = startDrag;
          repaint();
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                  Shape r;


        if (key.equals("l"))
        {
             r = makeLine(startDrag.x, startDrag.y, endDrag.x, endDrag.y);
        }



        if (key.equals("o"))
        {
             r = makeOval(startDrag.x, startDrag.y, endDrag.x, endDrag.y);
        }

        if (key.equals("r"))
        {
             r = makeRectangle(startDrag.x, startDrag.y, endDrag.x, endDrag.y);
        }


        else
        {
            r = makeCircle(startDrag.x, startDrag.y, endDrag.x, endDrag.y);
        }

          shapes.add(r);
          startDrag = null;
          endDrag = null;
          repaint();
        }
      });


      this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter()
      {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
          endDrag = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
          repaint();
        }
      });
    }
    private void paintBackground(Graphics2D g2){
      g2.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);



    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;




      for (Shape s : shapes)
      {
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(s);
        g2.fill(s);
      }

      if (startDrag != null && endDrag != null) {
        g2.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        Shape r;


        if (key.equals("l"))
        {
             r = makeLine(startDrag.x, startDrag.y, endDrag.x, endDrag.y);
        }



        if (key.equals("o"))
        {
             r = makeOval(startDrag.x, startDrag.y, endDrag.x, endDrag.y);
        }

        if (key.equals("r"))
        {
             r = makeRectangle(startDrag.x, startDrag.y, endDrag.x, endDrag.y);
        }


        else
        {
            r = makeCircle(startDrag.x, startDrag.y, endDrag.x, endDrag.y);
        }

        g2.draw(r);
      }
    }

    private Rectangle2D.Float makeRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
      return new Rectangle2D.Float(Math.min(x1, x2), Math.min(y1, y2), Math.abs(x1 - x2), Math.abs(y1 - y2));
    }

    private Ellipse2D.Float makeCircle(int cx1, int cy1, int cx2, int cy2)
    {
      return new Ellipse2D.Float(Math.min(cx1, cx2), Math.min(cy1, cy2), Math.abs(cx1 - cx2), Math.abs(cx1 - cx2));
    }

    private Ellipse2D.Float makeOval(int ox1, int oy1, int ox2, int oy2)
    {
      return new Ellipse2D.Float(Math.min(ox1, ox2), Math.min(oy1, oy2), Math.abs(ox1 - ox2), Math.abs(oy1 - oy2));
    }

        private Line2D.Float makeLine(int lx1, int ly1, int lx2, int ly2)
    {
      return new Line2D.Float(Math.min(lx1, lx2), Math.min(ly1, ly2), Math.abs(lx1 - lx2), Math.abs(ly1 - ly2));
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event)
    {
        key = event.getKeyText(event.getKeyCode());
    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event)
    {

    }

    //handle press of any action key
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event)
    {

    }

  }
}
```

......

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ShapeViewer
{

    //Creates and displays the application frame
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame ShapeViewer = new JFrame("Draw Stuff");
        ShapeViewer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ShapeViewer.getContentPane().add(new DrawShapes());

        ShapeViewer.pack();
        ShapeViewer.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

Comment: The method is not in `DrawShapes` class, but `PaintSurface`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but this is not in the DrawShape class, but in  it's private inner class PaintSurface. Move that method into the DrawShape class.

Comment: thanks, it compiles it but the program is completely wack unfortunately.

Comment: What do you mean, "it compiles it but the program is wack"? do you mean the code you posted compiles?

Comment: The program compiles fine, but when I try to run it and draw shapes such as ovals and circles I get a list of errors that I'm not sure how to understand or read. Here are the errors when I try to run the program. http://i.imgur.com/ZIZq2Jr.png

Comment: You have a NullPointerException, meaning you are calling a method, or trying to access an (instance) member of a variable you didn't initialize.
But I assume you got this by first moving the methods to the correct class?

Comment: Yes I found the error! The issue is that String key is not set to anything. I set String key=""; . However, the program only draws circles. It does not draw other things like rectangles when I press r or o.

Comment: String key = "";
so key IS initialized. This might lead to the problem somewhere, indeed, but key itself will not throw a NPE.

Comment: Yeah thats what I meant, it doesn't throw the NullPointer anymore, but now the program only draws circles and doesn't recognize when I press the keys "c" or "o" or draw the other shapes.